# Выделяется ли запятой слово "просто"?

Tags: пунктуация

Писал предыдущий вопрос и вспомнил еще об одном, который никак не могу для себя уяснить. А именно: нужно ли выделять запятой слово "просто" в предложениях типа "Просто(,) мне это интересно" или "Я(,) просто(,) хотел как лучше"?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В приведенных примерах слово "просто" является частицей и не обособляется. Она усиливает слово, к которому относится, или высказывание в целом, например: Этому  просто нельзя поверить. Просто невероятно!

Answer (score 5):

Запятые не нужны. В данном случае это частица. Да и паузы, как при вводном слове, здесь нет.

Comment: А вот интересно, почему наречие ПРОСТО используется в качестве усилительной частицы, например: это просто красиво, я просто не знаю, я просто очень спешу и др. Как, по вашему мнению, связаны по значению  наречие и частица?

Comment: Просто=без затей, не преувеличивая

Comment: Это многозначное слово. В примерах вопроса частица ПРОСТО = ТОЛЬКО (возможно ещё "не что иное, как"). Есть ещё значение частицы "действительно, в самом деле" :Этому просто нельзя поверить. Наречие ПРОСТО = СЛУЧАЙНО,БЕЗ НАМЕРЕНИЯ: Просто зашёл на огонёк.

Comment: Но есть еще: просто прелесть, просто красавица. Как  эти значения привести к слову "простой"  - элементарный, несложный, незамысловатый, обыкновенный?

Comment: > Есть ещё значение частицы "действительно, в самом деле"

И это значение как синоним "абсолютно достоверно, безотносительно истинно" подходит ко всем приведённым здесь примерам.

Comment: (Версия: почему вместо "действительно" появилось "просто"?). "Она же, действительно, прелесть!" (сказал бы Н. Г. Чернышевский - серьёзный, безулыбчивый) "Она же, без преувеличения, прелесть!" (сказал бы Ф. М. Достоевский - втихомолку восторженный, но осторожный) "Она же просто прелесть!" (сказал А. П. Чехов - "Краткость - сестра таланта")